# Combining hits from multiple documents into a single hit in Lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to get a particular search to work and it is proving problematic. The actual source data is quite complex but can be summarised by the following example:

> I have articles that are indexed so
>   that they can be searched. Each
>   article also has multiple properties
>   associated with it which are also
>   indexed and searchable. When users
>   search, they can get hits in either
>   the main article or the associated
>   properties. Regardless of where a hit
>   is achieved, the article is returned
>   as a search hit (ie. the properties
>   are never a hit in their own right).

Now for the complexity:

> Each property has security on it,
>   which means that for any given user,
>   they may or may not be able to see the
>   property. If a user cannot see a
>   property, they obviously do not get a
>   search hit in it. This security check
>   is proprietary and cannot be done
>   using the typical mechanism of storing
>   a role in the index alongside the
>   other fields in the document.

I currently have an index that contains the articles and properties indexed separately (ie. an article is indexed as a document, and each property has its own document). When a search happens, a hit in article A or a hit in any of the properties of article A should be classed as hit for article A alone, with the scores combined.

To achieve this originally, Lucene v1.3 was modified to allow this to happen by changing BooleanQuery to have a custom Scorer that could apply the logic of the security check and the combination of two hits in different documents being classed as a hit in a single document. I am trying to upgrade this version to the latest (v2.3.2 - I am using Lucene.Net), but ideally without having to modify Lucene in any way.

An additional problem occurs if I do an AND search. If an article contains the word *foo* and one of its properties contains the word *bar*, then searching for "foo AND bar" will return the article as a hit. My current code deals with this inside the custom Scorer.

Any ideas how/if this can be done?

*I am thinking along the lines of using a custom HitCollector and passing that into the search, but when doing the boolean search "foo AND bar", execution never reaches my HitCollector as the ConjunctionScorer filters out all of the results from the sub-queries before getting there.*

---

**EDIT:**

Whether or not a user can see a property is not based on the property itself, but on the value of the property. I cannot therefore put the extra security conditions into the query upfront as I don't know the value to filter by.

As an example:

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| Article | Property 1 | Property 2 |
+---------+------------+------------+
|    A    |     X      |     J      |
|    B    |     Y      |     K      |
|    C    |     Z      |     L      |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

If a user can see everything, then searching for "B and Y" will return a single search result for article B.

If another user cannot see a property if its value contains Y, then searching for "B and Y" will return no hits.

I have no way of knowing what values a user can and cannot see upfront. They only way to tell is to perform the security check (currently done at the time of filtering a hit from a field in the document), which I obviously cannot do for every possible data value for each user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having now implemented this (after a lot of head-scratching and stepping through Lucene searches), I thought I'd post back on how I achieved it.

Because I am interested in all of the results (ie. not a page at a time), I can avoid using the `Hits` object (which has been deprecated in later versions of Lucene anyway). This means I can do my own hit collection using the `Search(Weight, Filter, HitCollector)` method of `IndexSearcher`, iterating over all possible results and combining document hits as appropriate. To do this, I had to hook into Lucene's querying mechanism, but only when AND and NOT clauses are present. This is achieved by:

1. Creating a custom `QueryParser` and overriding `GetBooleanQuery(ArrayList, bool)` to return my own implementation.
2. Creating a custom `BooleanQuery` (returned from the custom `QueryParser`) and overriding `CreateWeight(Searcher)` to return my own implementation.
3. Creating a custom `Weight` (returned from the custom `BooleanQuery`) and overriding `Scorer(IndexReader)` to return my own implementation.
4. Creating a custom `BooleanScorer2` (returned from the custom `Weight`) and overriding the `Score(HitCollector)` method. This is what deals with the custom logic.

This might seem like a lot of classes, but most of them derive from a Lucene class and just override a single method.

The implementation of the `Score(HitCollector)` method in the custom `BooleanScorer2` class now has the responsibility of doing the custom logic. If there are no required sub-scorers, the scoring can be passed to the base `Score` method and run as normal. If there are required sub-scorers, it means there was a NOT or an AND clause in the query. In this case, the special combination logic mentioned in the question comes into play. I have a class called `ConjunctionScorer` that does this (this is not related to the `ConjunctionScorer` in Lucene).

The `ConjunctionScorer` takes a list of scorers and iterates over them. For each one, I extract the hits and their scores (using the `Doc()` and `Score()` methods) and create my own search hits collection containing only those hits that the current user can see after performing the relevant security checks. If a hit has already been found by another scorer, I combine them together (using the mean of their scores for their new score). If a hit is from a prohibited scorer, I remove the hit if it was already found.

At the end of all of this, I set the hits onto the `HitCollector` passed into the `BooleanScorer2.Score(HitCollector)` method. This is a custom `HitCollector` that I passed into the `IndexSearcher.Search(Query, HitCollector)` method to originally perform the search. When this method returns, my custom `HitCollector` now contains my search results combined together as I wanted.

Hopefully this information will be useful to someone else faced with the same problem. It sounds like a lot of effort, but it is actually pretty trivial. Most of the work is done in combining the hits together in the `ConjunctionScorer`. Note that this is for Lucene v2.3.2, and may be different in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

Review just another way

> This security check is proprietary and
>   cannot be done using the typical
>   mechanism of storing a role in the
>   index alongside the other fields in
>   the document.

What about checking the permission of property on query building stage? So if property explicitly hidden from user avoid including it to result tree

Comment: The security check is not based on the property, but on the value of the property. A user might be able to see (the value of) property A for article A, but not see (the value of) property A for article B.

Comment: I see. Ok, what about methods:  
Searcher.Search(Query query, HitCollector results)

Or

Search(Query query, Filter filter, HitCollector results)

You pass hit collector explicitly, so you solve problem with AND query.
(I'm looking on Lucene.Net.2.3.1)

Comment: I have already tried that, but the HitCollector never gets called as it is deemed that there are no results that contain both terms from the query, meaning there are no hits to collect.

Comment: A-ha! then you need Lucene.Net.Search.MultiSearcher - accepts multiple searchers (your case: articles & properties). After it hitcollector will accept all calls

Comment: How does that deal with the AND search? I've tried a quick demo with two separate indices (one for articles and one for properties) and searching for "b AND y" still returns no results as each index does indeed contain no results for the AND query.

Comment: Hmmm, you have talking about absence (at lucene level) relation between article and property. May be you need not AND, but another set operation (multiplication , 'OR')